# Java code to solve dynamic equation with one unknown

Tags: java, equation

I my program there are various equations such as `x = y + z`.

When the user has input all but one of the equation-variables, I want my program to
calculate the unknown:

User inputs `y=5 and z=2` --> `unknown x = 5 + 2 = 7`

User inputs `x=1 and y=3` --> `unknown z = 1 - 3 = -2`

I have many equations and want to avoid to manually have to isolate every variabel...hope u understand.

I've tried both JEP and JScience, both without luck.

Comment: So there will be n variables, with n-1 given? What are the mathematical operators allowed in your environment? (+ and -, obviously, any others?). Will bracketed expressions be allowed?

Comment: Also, will each variable only appear once int the equation?  Will only the first equation feature multiple variables, and the rest are just simple assignments like "y=10"?

Comment: Yes n variables, with n-1 given. Operators include +,-,*,/,^2,sqrt. Yes every variable will only appear once. The user is prompted for input, when enough inputs are had (which is n-1) the program can calculate the unknown. Dependant on which variables the user chooses input the equation could be eg. "10 = x + 20" or "10 = 5 + y" or z = 0.24 + 5.24...

Comment: What raises the problem is that I have many equations like: x = (z + y - z) / (i^2 * g), and it is not neccesarily x that is the single unknown. I want to be spared of typing all variations of the equation, where I would have to isolate every variable - in this case giving me 6 different equations ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about [JbcParser](http://www.bestcode.com/html/jbcparser.html)?  It is commercial with a small cost so I do not know if this disqualifies it from consideration.  This belongs to the same class of parsers you are investigating.  They do have an online demo which you can play around with at least to see if it does meet your needs.